# onPause android application

Tags: android, onpause, activity-lifecycle

I have read through the Android Activity Lifecycle but I'm still confused about it. If activity X is started after MainActivity, will the main activity be paused automatically (by the system) or should we call `onPause()` in MainActivity.java?

If the system calls it automatically, how can we release e.g. the camera?
Otherwise, if we call `onPause()` manually in MainActivity.java, if users press the back button, would the app release the camera as well? What should we do if we want to release the camera for starting activity X and want to release an animation when users press the back button?

I'm new to Android and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The system calls all `onXXXX` methods automatically, you never call any of them (Unless, of course, you have defined some on your own). Any cleanup can be done in `onPause` or `onStop`, preferably `onStop`.

Comment: "Preferably onPause". There is no guaranty of onStop() being called everytime your app is closed. Android can close the app without calling onStop() or onDestroy();

Answer (score 0):

The system handles the starting/pausing/deleting of an activity if something happens that suggest that those actions should be taken (a phone call, the user pressed the back/home button, an intent is raised) so you don't need to call them manually.

You should however manage your resources inside those methods, if there is a need for it. For instance an `Asynctask` that is populating a list.

I would recommend reading through the docs about managing the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)